# How to change pandas timestamps to python datetime objects?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, pytz

I am searching for a way to change pandas timestamps to python datetime objects and I am failing. I used to_pydatetime().

Below is my code with comments:

```
import pandas
import datetime
import pytz

forced_UTC = pytz.timezone("Europe/London").localize(datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 9, 5)).tzinfo
forced_BST = pytz.timezone("Europe/London").localize(datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 27, 9, 5)).tzinfo
#print (forced_UTC, forced_BST)

# Create dataframe and check the value of the first element in the column.
my_df = pandas.DataFrame({"my_column": ["2019-04-01 00:15:00", "2019-02-23 13:00:00", "2019-02-23 14:00:00"]})
first_date = my_df["my_column"].iloc[0]
print (first_date, type(first_date)) # 2019-04-01 00:15:00 <class 'str'>

# Change every element in the column from string to datetime object.
my_df["my_column"] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(element, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=forced_UTC) for element in my_df["my_column"]]
first_date = my_df["my_column"].iloc[0]
print (first_date, type(first_date)) # <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
# Didn't work, thought it would make them python datetime objects.

# Try creating a new list and replacing the column.
list_to_replace = [element.to_pydatetime() for element in my_df["my_column"]] # make all timestamps datetimes
print (list_to_replace[0],type(list_to_replace[0])) # 2019-04-01 01:15:00+01:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
my_df["my_column"] = [element for element in list_to_replace]
first_date = my_df["my_column"].iloc[0] 
print (first_date, type(first_date))# 2019-04-01 01:15:00+01:00 <class pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
# Didn't work.

# Use to_pydatetime() doesn't work either
print (first_date.to_pydatetime(), type(first_date)) # 2019-04-01 01:15:00+01:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

# Using to_pydatetime() like this works!?!?!?!
first_date = my_df["my_column"].iloc[0].to_pydatetime()
print (first_date, type(first_date)) # 2019-04-01 01:15:00+01:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>

# print (datetime.datetime.strftime(first_date, "%H"))
# print (datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 0, 15, tzinfo=forced_BST) > first_date)
```

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm finding the comments hard to follow. I think they say when you call `to_pydatetime()` you get what you want, so I'm not clear what you are asking.

Comment: It works when I do it for 1 element, but when I call the function for all the elements and try to replace the column of the dataframe it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but you were printing the `type` without modifying the type.
Here, you are printing indeed a panda date (`first_date`) and a panda type (`type(first_date)`).

```
first_date = my_df["my_column"].iloc[0] 
print (first_date, type(first_date)) # 2019-04-01 01:15:00+01:00 <class pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
# Didn't work.
```

In this case, you are printing a python date (`first_date.to_pydatetime()`) since you are indeed using `to_pydatetime`, but the `first_date` variable was never modified, so it's `type` is still a panda date .

```
print (first_date.to_pydatetime(), type(first_date)) # 2019-04-01 01:15:00+01:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

And here you are also **overwriting** the `first_date` variable with the python date, (`first_date = first_date.to_pydatetime()`) that is why you consider it is working only then. So now `first_date` will be a python date, and `type(first_date)` will, consequently, return what you expected

```
# Using to_pydatetime() like this works!?!?!?!
first_date = my_df["my_column"].iloc[0].to_pydatetime()
print (first_date, type(first_date)) # 2019-04-01 01:15:00+01:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: Hey, I get the 2nd and 3rd comment you make but I don't get the first one about modifying the type. Can you explain it further?

`list_to_replace` has only python datetime objects. So me dropping them into the column should have worked right?

Comment: @Lev edited, I hope it clarifies it now. You're indeed on the right path